# How to manage Ubuntu monitor from Windows 10 via usb cable

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors

hello fellow ubuntu users,

So I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS next to my Windows 10 as a dual boot.
And I have 3 monitors connected to my computer (GPU is gtx 970) one via HDMI and one via VGA and one is also connected via VGA but it has a usb device in between(USB 2.0 Graphics Adapter from koning).

So here is the problem. On my windows 10 installation I always used display link to manage my third monitor but I can't quite get that to work on Ubuntu. I was wondering if there is anyone that could help me with this problem. Maybe direct me to another software program to manage my third monitor.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

DisplayLink provides Ubuntu software, too: http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

Or you might be able to use xrandr, or the control center GUI.

Edit: Sorry, just realized you had tried it.  What wasn't working?  Do you have error output you could post?

Comment: I am not at my ubuntu pc right now but what I remember from trying to install is that I didn't get any error messages or something I just installed the thing but I didn't detect anything nor could I find any Display link software installed on my ubuntu but I will give you further details once I am home.